# Interpenetration of regression coefficient in my case

Tags: regression, interpretation

I run a regression between Gender, age as IVs and cholesterol as a dependent variable. The coefficient of gender is -0.57 (male=1,female=0) and the coefficient of age is 0.4. Now I am wondering how I can explain these coefficients?

Comment: **Interpenetration???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of gender means:

> If I sample two data points from my population, and observe that they have the same age, but different genders, then I expect that, on average, the difference in cholesterol I will observe is -0.57.

The coefficient of age means:

> If I sample two data points from my population, and observe that they have the same gender, but one is exactly one year older than another, then I expect that, on average, the difference in cholesterol I will observe is 0.4.

These interpretations are contingent on the regression being a good fit to the data.  I.e., if the actual relationship between age and cholesterol is non-linear (i.e. quadratic, exponential, or something more exotic) then taking these interpretations at face value is not advisable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Can I say: As age increases by one unit, cholesterol will increase by 0.4 units on average as long as we have the same gender.  2.Men compare to women, have 57% less cholesterol as long as age held constant.?

Comment: Those seem ok, just a bit more informal.

Comment: @ Matthew Drury, so using 57% less is appropriate?

Comment: 57% could be appropriate only if your response variable is measured in %. If your response is measured in other units (for example, mg/cm3) then expected cholesterol for me would have 57 units less (or more) than women of the same age.